# What are the types of statistical tests/analysis which I can do here?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics

I am writing my Master Thesis on the concept of 4-day work week...this is about how employees instead of working 5 days a week...work only for 4 days a week...since the concept is relatively new..mine is an exploratory study...

In this study there are three parts -

***Part 1*** - I cover the advantages and disadvantages of the concept..
Part 1 has its own separate research question...

***Part 2*** - I discuss about the two real-world trials which were carried out on the concept...
Part 2 has its own separate research question...

***Part 3*** - Since the concept is new and not widely used..in this part I try to judge the employee's perception about the concept of four-day work week...that is how they view working as per a four day work week..

***Part 3 again has a separate question which is " How do employees in Australia perceive the concept of 4 day work week ?"***

There are no other hypotheses in my Project...only the above Research Questions...which are different for each of the 3 parts..

I have to answer the research question of Part 3 with an online survey whose questionnaire I have already prepared.. I have not started passing the survey around.. just in case I need to change anything in it.. that is make some questions mandatory or not...Although I am not sure how many qualified responses would be enough..but I plan to gather closely 130-140 responses(a qualified response is a response in which it is established that the person is currently an employee in Australia or has previously been an employee in Australia)..i will check this later...at this stage i need to be little bit clear about the analysis part...

The overall objective of my Thesis/study is to develop set of general guidelines for employers who are trying to implement this concept in order to help them understand whether if it makes sense to implement the concept of 4 day work week or not and if they want to implement it what are the factors that they need to consider..

For my Survey, I have established that there are 6-7 independent variables and there is only a single dependent variable.

To explain what I need to do and for sake of simplicity, I list only 2 Independent variables and the 1 Dependent variable as below -

***Independent Variable 1*** - Category under which the respondent's employer can be categorized into ?

Option 1 - Government
Option 2 - Private
Option 3 - Other

***Independent variable 2*** - Respondent's gender ?
Option 1 - Male
Option 2 - Female
Option 3 - Other

**Dependent Variable** - Willingness of the employee to work as per a Four day work week ?
Option 1 - Yes
Option 2 - No
Option 3 - Maybe

I will take the survey only once and after I have all the responses I will start analysis and developing my guidelines

Depending on the responses of the survey and the analysis I would like to see for eg. -
If there are people who have selected their employer type as "Government" and said that they are not willing to work as per a 4-day work week..

Then my guideline would include something like - Employers who are Government entities need to be vary of adopting a four-day work week as employees do not seem to like it..

Similarly if the respondents select "Government" as their employer type and for willingness to work as per four-day work week ..select "Yes".. then my guidelines would be Employers who are Government entities need to consider implementing a four-day work week as the study shows that the employees are in favour of it...

Similarly for Employer type "Other" and when they select willingness - Yes or No ..then a recommendation accordingly...

So ..
Government v/s. Yes,
Government v/s. No,
Government v/s. Other

Hence, whichever option stands out I can give out a recommendation accordingly...

Similar type of analysis for the Gender variable against the willingness variable...

Additionally similar analysis for all the other independent variables against the dependent variables of Willingness..

My professor has told me that I need to do statistical analysis..what exact type he did not specify..and I cannot ask him at this moment...i need to present him something and then maybe he gives me a feedback...However, in my case considering the stage I am currently in...my Research Objective and my Research Questions and the Survey Questionnaire will not change..so i think for Part 3 - doing analysis as above will be most appropriate and in line with my Research Question and the Research Objective -

Hence, in my case can anyone tell me what type of Statistical Analysis or Tests i need to do in order to check the variables as described above ?

If you require any additional information, please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: I just noticed a important detail in my Thesis Supervision Guide which I have received from the professor - 

I quote the following sections from it:

"Primary data are best presented in tables and figures. You will subsequently apply the methods for data analysis described in the Research Design section to the results to gain de-rived data, such as a statistic. 1/n

Comment: However, don't use statistics unless you have a reasonable sample size. The minimal sample size is determined by the required precision and confidence interval, the population size, and the sample proportion. Recommendations for random sampling are given in Table.   2/n

Comment: Margin of Error                                 Size of Population
                                    200            500          1000           5000           >5000        
     ± 3%                       170             340            520             900             1100
     ± 5%                       130             220            280             360             390
    ± 10%                      65               80               90                 95             100

Comment: In this case, 

1) How can I know what is the margin of error for my population...that is employees in Australia ? How to calculate it ?

2) If I get for e.g. margin of error as ± 5%, does this mean that I need to collect atleast 390 responses for my survey in order to do statistical analysis ?

3) If I presume the answer for 2) as Yes...and if I do not have 390 responses for my survey...then i need to do just descriptive statistics..am i correct ?

Thanks,